# Handling fastcgi_param with HHVM fastcgi in Nginx

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, hhvm

Is it correct that HHVM via fastcgi into Nginx doesn't support fastcgi_param? And if so, how can this be resolved?

Like:

```
location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires        off;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9999; <- my hhvm is set to port 9999 io 9000
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/report/PHP.error.log";
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE admin;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Can't get them passed into PHP myself either. I'm gonna check the HHVM settings rather than Nginx conf.

Comment: Any luck with this? Looks like its possible, https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1650 but I guess I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Hi @DylanMadisetti I was unable to check it yet, maybe the answer is also in here: https://github.com/danslo/hhvm/

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, I can confirm that hhvm server with `server.type = fastcgi` does implement fastcgi parameters and does work with the `fastcgi_param` nginx directive.

Your nginx location block seems a little incomplete to me. I would suggest implementing at least all the directives found in the official HHVM doc https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/FastCGI#making-it-work-with-nginx.

I believe you need to at least have these directives within your php location block handler's scope.

- `root`
- `fastcgi_index`

Also, please make sure your hhvm config (php.ini) is set up correctly for fastcgi.